# Have more than one user registration page for Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, captcha

I currently have an iOS app that is built and functioning except for one slight problem.  I would like to retain CAPTCHA whenever an anonymous user creates an account via the web (using Drupal's user registration form).  However, I would like to have another URL that houses the same Drupal registration form (without CAPTCHA) so that users can create an account from within the iOS app (app connects to Drupal site using Drupal iOS SDK and userRegister function).

Is this possible in Drupal 6?  Is there a way to clone the user_register form such that the original form has CAPTCHA and lives at mysite.com/user/register whereas user_register_clone form does not have CAPTCHA and lives at mysite.com/user/register/mobile?

Thanks in advance and have a great day/night!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the autoassignrole (http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module there is a clear example of cloning the user register form and creating a register process in a different page than register.

The module assign user roles based on the path the user is creating the account from.

So you could check the module's code for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, jzerpa--that's exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, jzerpa--that's exactly what I was trying to do!

I installed the autoassignrole module and tried to do exactly what you described.  For the node section, I created a new URL such that mysite/user/register/mobile now exists in addition to mysite/user/register.  When I click on "Create New Account" on mysite, it correctly goes to mysite/user/register.  However, I can't figure out how to change the form at mysite/user/register/mobile to be without CAPTCHA and not affect the form at mysite/user/register.  I looked at autoassignrole.module and .inc and am still stuck.

Comment: You could create a hook_form_alter to try to eliminate the form variables that have the captcha but just in the mobile version by checking the current path. I did some test and it works, here is some code that could help.

http://pastebin.com/v3sAxZ7C

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for--thank you, jzerpa!!!!  I hope I can find a way to repay you!!

Now, just to make sure I'm understanding everything correctly, I will state my game plan.  I will create two files, mobileRegistration.module and mobileRegistration.info.  I will include the code in the link you provided in the mobileRegistration.module file (and appropriately change variable and path names).  That being said, is dpm($form) necessary?  Will unset($form['captcha']) work?

Thanks again!!!!!!

Comment: :-D Glad it helped. The dpm function is just for you to check the variables of the form (In case that you use a different module instead of mollom). I tested locally unseting $form['captcha'] and it worked. Do more tests and reply if you have more troubles.